# After leaving activity and returning very soon, glClear fails with GL_OUT_OF_MEMORY

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

The error appears on android, after leaving the app, and returning very fast. (*onPause* and *onResume* are triggered, but not *onStop*, *onStart*). The EGL surface is destroyed and recreated, but the context is kept. In all other scenarios the error does not appear, and rendering goes fine (eg starting app, or leaving the app and returning not so fast)

I'm checking for errors right before `glClear`, and right after it. If I comment it, the error will appear at the next `glDrawElements`. So I suppose it is something that is not correctly configured. Which could be the reasons for this error?

```
GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Comment: If you are working on android, you are using opengl-es. And please fix the typo in your title.

Comment: "onPause and onStop are triggered" - probably you mean onPause and onResume

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that although I was destroying the surface with eglDestroySurface, I was not calling:

```
EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(mEGLDisplay, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, mEGLContext);
```

After adding the line above, it runs fine.